# Vue not listening event

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have problem with my Vue app. I'm trying to make connection to pusher and retrieve data with laravel echo. I have installed and configured everything on backend side, but front end is not working.
This is my app.js file:

```
    import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
    
    window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
    
    window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key: 'mykey',
        wsHost: '127.0.0.1',
        wsPort: 6001,
        cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
        forceTLS: false,
        disableStats: true,
    });

    import './src/main.js'
```

And this is my file where I'm getting all data, even post method, post method is broken as well but this is easy fix, problem is listening events.

```
<template>
<div id="demo-basic-card">
<div class="vx-row">
  <div class="vx-col w-full sm:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 mb-base">
                <vx-card class="globaxy-add p-2" @click="add = true, addButton = false">
                    <div class="text-center">

                    <div v-if="addButton" :style="{animation: 'fadeIn 1.3s'}">
                      <feather-icon icon="PlusIcon" class="p-10 inline-flex rounded-full globaxy-add-plus" :class="[`text-success`, {'mb-10': !iconRight}]" :style="{background: `rgba(var(--vs-success),.15)`}"></feather-icon>
                      <h4>Add New</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div v-if="add" :style="{animation: 'fadeIn 1s'}">
                    <form v-on:submit.prevent="submitForm">
                      <div class="vx-row">
                        <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/2 w-full mb-2">
                          <vs-input class="w-full" label-placeholder="Name" :value="addServer.name" :v-model="addServer.name" name="name"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/2 w-full mb-2">
                          <vs-input class="w-full" label-placeholder="IP" :value="addServer.ip" :v-model="addServer.ip" name="ip" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="vx-row">
                        <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/2 w-full mb-2">
                          <vs-input class="w-full" label-placeholder="Password" :value="addServer.password" :v-model="addServer.password" name="password"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/2 w-full mb-2">
                          <vs-input class="w-full" @keyup.enter="createServer" label-placeholder="User" :v-model="addServer.user" :value="addServer.user" name="user" />
                        </div>
                    
                      </div>
                  
                      <div class="vx-row">
                        <div class="vx-col w-full">
                     
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </vx-card>
    </div>
    <div class="vx-col w-full sm:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 mb-base" v-for="device in adminServers" :key="device.id" :style="{animation: 'zoomIn ' +  (device.id * 0.3) + 's'}">
        <div class="display" @mouseover="hover = true" @mouseleave="hover = false">
                <vx-card class="globaxy-card p-2">
                    <router-link :to="'/administration/server/' + device.id"><vs-button v-if="hover" class="manage-server" radius color="primary" type="gradient" icon-pack="feather" :style="{animation: 'zoomIn 0.6s'}" icon="icon-edit"></vs-button></router-link>
                  <feather-icon icon="ServerIcon" class="p-5 inline-flex rounded-full" :class="[`text-success`, {'mb-4': !iconRight}]" :style="{background: `rgba(var(--vs-success),.15)`}"></feather-icon>
                    <div class="text-center">
                    <span class="device-name">{{ device.name }}</span>
                        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" :href="'http://' + device.domain"><h4>{{ device.domain }}</h4></a></h4>
                        <p class="text-grey">{{ device.ip }}</p>
                    </div>

                </vx-card>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import Administration from "@/http/Administration";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      iconRight: false,
      addButton: true,
      hover: false,
      add: false,
      selected: [],
      'tableList': [
        'vs-th: Component',
        'vs-tr: Component',
        'vs-td: Component',
        'thread: Slot',
        'tbody: Slot',
        'header: Slot'
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
            ...mapGetters(["adminServers"]),
            ...mapGetters(["addServer"]),
        },

        mounted() {
          window.Echo.channel("addServer").listen(".server-created", e => {
            this.$store.commit("ADD_SERVER", e.server);
            this.addServer.name = "";
            this.addServer.ip = "";
            this.addServer.password = "";
            this.addServer.user = "";
          });
          console.log(window.Echo.channel("addServer").listen(".server-created"))
          this.$store.dispatch("GET_SERVERS");
        },
        

        methods:{
          createServer() {
            this.$store.dispatch("ADD_SERVER", this.addServer);
          },

        }
}

</script>
```

Everything else is configured good (I believe), because everything works except cathcing data realtime.

This is how is data returned in console when I run 'php artisan websockets:serve':

> Connection id 442760083.70152140 sending message
> {"event":"log-message","channel":"private-websockets-dashboard-api-message","data":{"type":"api-message","time":"17:15:26","details":"Channel:
> addServer, Event:
> server-created","data":"{"servers":{"id":26,"name":"Test","ip":"12.2.223.1","user":"root","password":"asdasdasdasda","domain":null,"mysql_password":null,"ssh_port":22,"ftp_port":null,"isActive":null,"created_at":"2021-01-07T17:15:26.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-07T17:15:26.000000Z"}}"}}

And when I console.log all events from pusher I have"

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
> at Channel.Dispatcher.emit (app.js:69745)
> at Channel.handleEvent (app.js:70511)
> at app.js:72629
> at ConnectionManager.Dispatcher.emit (app.js:69745)
> at message (app.js:71045)
> at Connection.Dispatcher.emit (app.js:69745)
> at message (app.js:70302)
> at TransportConnection.Dispatcher.emit (app.js:69745)
> at TransportConnection.onMessage (app.js:69873)
> at WebSocket.socket.onmessage (app.js:69890) Dispatcher.emit @ app.js:69745 Channel.handleEvent @ app.js:70511 (anonymous) @
> app.js:72629 Dispatcher.emit @ app.js:69745 message @ app.js:71045
> Dispatcher.emit @ app.js:69745 message @ app.js:70302 Dispatcher.emit
> @ app.js:69745 TransportConnection.onMessage @ app.js:69873
> socket.onmessage @ app.js:69890 app.js:122971 [Vue warn]: Error in
> render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"
>
> found in
>
> --->  at resources/js/src/views/Administration/Pages/Servers.vue
>  at resources/js/src/layouts/main/Main.vue
>  at resources/js/src/App.vue
>  warn @ app.js:122971 logError @ app.js:124230 globalHandleError @ app.js:124225 handleError @ app.js:124185
> Vue._render @ app.js:125890 updateComponent @ app.js:126404 get @
> app.js:126815 run @ app.js:126890 flushSchedulerQueue @ app.js:126648
> (anonymous) @ app.js:124326 flushCallbacks @ app.js:124252
> Promise.then (async) timerFunc @ app.js:124279 nextTick @
> app.js:124336 queueWatcher @ app.js:126740 update @ app.js:126880
> notify @ app.js:123082 mutator @ app.js:123234 ADD_SERVER @
> app.js:163382 wrappedMutationHandler @ app.js:152624 commitIterator @
> app.js:152246 (anonymous) @ app.js:152245
> _withCommit @ app.js:152404 commit @ app.js:152244 boundCommit @ app.js:152189 (anonymous) @ 91.js:98 Dispatcher.emit @ app.js:69745
> Channel.handleEvent @ app.js:70511 (anonymous) @ app.js:72629
> Dispatcher.emit @ app.js:69745 message @ app.js:71045 Dispatcher.emit
> @ app.js:69745 message @ app.js:70302 Dispatcher.emit @ app.js:69745
> TransportConnection.onMessage @ app.js:69873 socket.onmessage @
> app.js:69890 app.js:124234 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of
> undefined
> at 91.js:346
> at Proxy.renderList (app.js:124974)
> at Proxy.render (91.js:342)
> at VueComponent.Vue._render (app.js:125888)
> at VueComponent.updateComponent (app.js:126404)
> at Watcher.get (app.js:126815)
> at Watcher.run (app.js:126890)
> at flushSchedulerQueue (app.js:126648)
> at Array. (app.js:124326)
> at flushCallbacks (app.js:124252)

What could be a problem?

Comment: That's a lot of code, are you sure it's a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

device.id is none check why these property is not defined

Comment: Well I can't find what is wrong, it's clearly in template when I'm listing servers. Because when I refresh page and click on server, there is device.id, but when I send event it's coming with this error.

Comment: I have deleted all device.id and then problem is with the name, probbably when I delete name as well, it will show something.

Comment: You could also add {{adminServers}} befor the vfor to inspect the element

Comment: Fixed, I just needed to create another component